# jqueryui combobox appearance wrong in table inside dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the JQuery UI code for the autocomplete combobox. I've made no changes at all other than to specify the id of the selects to be made into comboboxes. It works OK on the main page, but when placed inside a jqueryUI dialog box, the drop down list disappears until the length of it has passed the bottom edge of the dialog box, then the rest of it appears below the dialog box. It seems like its layer is below that of the dialog box. Also, the combobox widget itself does not respect the table cell or table it is inside of; it flows past the right border of the cell/table. Does anybody have any suggestions on how these issues should be remedied?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code, and idealy post a fiddle demonstrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution on another similar StackOverflow question:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    position:absolute;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:4000 !important
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

I tried your solution, but it only works once. Have you an updated solution?